# Why is it bad to change for loop counter in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, programming-languages

I often heard that it's bad to modify the loop counter in the body of a for loop. The following (bad) example shows what I am talking about.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    i++;
}
```

I know that this would be allowed within while loops but could anybody explain why this is a bad practice in Java resp. even a problem in any programming language.

Comment: It's bad in the sense that you won't be able to determine how many times you'll go through the loop just by looking at the condition, making maintenance harder. Comes down to readability. But there isn't anything that explicitly doesn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could there show up any problems concerning the functionality of a software or the Java VM? I heard about problems in other programming languages. Do you have examples for that?

Comment: None in Java or the other C-derived languages, AFAIK. Not if the conditions are correct. You can have issues with equality, though (e.g.: `for (int i=0; i==10; i++) { i+=10; }`), or if you increment in the loop but decrement in the body (e.g.: `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { i--; }`). Potentially also issues if you're going through an array, and change the index before reading, which could lead to exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Thomas I suggest you listen to @AntonH 's advice in his comments, they are all good!

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons why this is bad:

1. Readability. `for( a; b; c ) { d; }` is a shorthand for `a; while( b ) { d; c; }` explicitly for the case where you are iterating over a list. It is not strictly needed in the language. The whole point of having it is to imply intent: "I want to iterate over an entire list" or "I want to iterate over part of a list in sequence, then abort when I find something" at most.

   If you add an additional increment, that will surprise other people encountering your code. If your `c` above says `++x` or whatever, people will simply *assume* it loops over all items, just to then find "surprise! not always!".

   OTOH, if you use a while loop, people only see the condition, and are alerted that this will be a more complex loop where the increment will not be constant.
2. Optimiziation. Given the above statement of intent, some optimizers will generate different code for a `for` statement than a `while` statement. Although none of them should generate wrong code, they might apply an optimization that has worse performance characteristics for non-sequential access than for sequential access.

   And by "worse performance characteristics" I mean they may tell the CPU to cache the wrong code path and slow down your execution by a fraction of a cycle because data may have to be loaded into the CPU again after having needlessly been flushed.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly because most of the programmers use it that way, so it is more readable for everyone as mentioned by @AntonH.

Side note: trying as in other language (like C if memory serves) to write:

```
for(int i =0; i< 10; i){
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
    }
```

This code compiles and run. In Java, the equivalent:

```
for(int i =0; i< 10; i){
        System.out.println("%d", i);
        i++;
    }
```

**Edited thanks to @David Wallace**:This yields a compilation error, it is mandatory to have an assignement in the statement part of the for loop.

Comment: Actually, the two compilation errors in your Java snippet are not for the reason you state.  It's perfectly legal to increment or decrement the iterator variable in Java.

Comment: It is. I wrote "to not", like you are not allowed to have a non incremented (or decremented) variable in the statement part of the for loop, as opposed to C for instance. My bad for the ambiguous statement.

Comment: My apologies, I misread it.  But, actually, it is also legal not to increment or decrement the iterator variable.  So although I misread your sentence, it's still wrong.  If you supply something in the third clause of the `for` statement, it has to be an assignment, but not necessarily an increment or decrement.  So `for(int i = 0;  i < 10; i = 0)` is legal, for example.

Comment: Fair enough, actually I was not aware of that since on the Oracle website, they call the statement the "increment" (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). My thanks, I learnt an interesting thing.

Comment: You don't need a third clause in the `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at what happens with this code:

```
1 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
2     i++;
3 }
```

1. Initially line 1 i=0.
2. Line 2 increments i, which now equals 1.
3. End of loop, so i++ takes effect, now i=2.
4. And so on ...

So if you really wanted to do something like this, you could have wrote it like:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i+=2) {
}
```

Which gets the same result. It's not necessarily bad code, but it doesn't make sense to code like that, and it's very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: In the second loop, I think you meant `i+=2`

Comment: Ok, but what if you want to increment the counter twice only under some circumstances but only once by default?

Comment: @ThomasMaier Then you use `if`.

Comment: Yes, this would be possible for the first solution but not for the second, right?

Comment: @ThomasMaier Correct. Although you have the possibility with the second of having `for (int i=0; i<10; i+=2) { if(someCondition) { i--; } }`. Yes, it's ugly, but functionally similar. I can't really be more precise, since I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish.